# deleting solr 3.5.0 index completely

Tags: solr

I've created several indices in my `solr` : `test1, test2,test3...`

now what I want to do is to **COMPLETELY** remove them

the following will remove the data inside of the index **test1** but does not delete the index itself as the `index` still showing in **solr admin** . (inspired from [here](https://gist.github.com/nz/673027) )

```
curl http://index.websolr.com/solr/test1/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

I'm hoping for an approach to not get my hands dirty by removing directories manually and restarting solr (thus potentially avoiding to damage the **solr**).

is there anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=test1
```

The UNLOAD action removes a core from Solr.

So with your requirement you can try

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=test1&deleteIndex=true&deleteDataDir=true
```

here deleteDataDir is what you are looking for which is - If deleteDataDir is true, removes the data directory and all sub-directories.

OR

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=test1&deleteInstanceDir=true
```

For other param please check the following link.

[UNLOAD Solr Core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-UNLOAD)

Comment: a quick question mate,  by "coer=core0"  you mean "core=test1" right?

Comment: I gonna try it. finger crossed, its not gonna bust it  out :D